# Using Java 8 Optional for safe Map traversal

Tags: java, groovy, lambda

I have `Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap` in my Java 8 class.  I need to navigate to a leaf String like `myMap['keyA']['keyB']`, returning `null` if either `'keyA'` or `'keyB'` does not exist in the correlating Map.

In groovy I would use `myMap?.keyA?.keyB` and be done with it.  I understand that Java 8's `Optional<T>` brings similar behavior into java.  Is there a way to use this new behavior to concisely mimic the groovy functionality?  If not, is there another concise way to get this behavior in Java 8, or am I still stuck with elaborate procedural code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Optional`'s `ofNullable` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) to create an `Optional` that may or may not represent a `null` value.  Then you can use [the `map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) that will, with a `Function`, map the result to a new value if the value wasn't already `null`.

Here, I supply a `Function` as a lambda expression to get the value from the second `Map` using the second key.

```
Optional<String> result = Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyA")).map(m -> m.get("keyB"));
```

From there you can see if the `Optional` has a value with `isPresent()`, and if so, get it with `get()`.

Testing:

```
public static Optional<String> method(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map,
    String key1, String key2)
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key1)).map(m -> m.get(key2));
}
```

Calling Code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> inner = new HashMap<>();
inner.put("one", "two");
myMap.put("three", inner);
System.out.println(method(myMap, "three", "one"));
System.out.println(method(myMap, "three", "dne"));
System.out.println(method(myMap, "dne", "dne"));
```

Output:

```
Optional[two]
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

Answer (score 11):

```
String valueOrNull = Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyA"))
                             .map(x -> x.get("keyB"))
                             .orElse(null);
```

First, it wraps the results of the first lookup in an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), which acts as a monad. If you add a third layer (`myMap.?keyA.?keyB.?keyC`), it would look like this:

```
String valueOrNull = Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get("keyA"))
                             .map(x -> x.get("keyB"))
                             .map(x -> x.get("keyC"))
                             .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

You can consider using recursion.

```
/**
* Finds the value of a node in nested maps.
* @return leaf value or null if none
*/
public <K, V> V getValueFromKeys(Map<K, V> map, K... keys) {
    V value = map.getOrDefault(keys[0], null);
    if (keys.length == 1) return value;
    if (value instanceof Map) {
        K[] remainingKeys = Arrays.copyOfRange(keys, 1, keys.length);
        return getValueFromKeys((Map<K, V>) value, remainingKeys);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will work with Java >= 8 (you can easily adapt it to previous versions).

Bonus (needs Guava):

```
@Test
public void getValueFromKeys_level1() {
    Map<String, String> mapLevel1 = ImmutableMap.of("key1", "value1");

    assertEquals("value1", getValueFromKeys(mapLevel1, "key1"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel1, null));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel1, ""));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel1, "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel1, "key1", "wrong"));
}

@Test
public void getValueFromKeys_level2() {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapLevel2 = ImmutableMap.of("key1", ImmutableMap.of("subkey1", "value1"));

    assertEquals("value1", getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, "key1", "subkey1"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, null));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, ""));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, "key1", "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, "key1", "subkey1", "wrong"));
    assertTrue(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel2, "key1") instanceof Map);
}

@Test
public void getValueFromKeys_level3() {
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> mapLevel3 = ImmutableMap.of("key1", ImmutableMap.of("subkey1", ImmutableMap.of("subsubkey1", "value1")));

    assertEquals("value1", getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, "key1", "subkey1", "subsubkey1"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, null));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, ""));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, "key1", "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, "key1", "subkey1", "wrong"));
    assertNull(getValueFromKeys(mapLevel3, "key1", "subkey1", "subsubkey1", "wrong"));
}
```